# Как подключить System.Windows.Data?

Tags: база-данных, .net, visual-studio

В проекте требуется использовать BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings. Пространство имён System.Windows.Data. Visual Studio в строке-подсказке предлагает System.Windows.Forms а  System.Windows.Data отсутствует. Если его написать, ругается

> Namespase or type  specified in Imports  System.Windows.Data doesn’t contain any public member or cannot be found

Очевидно у меня что-то не установлено. Переустановка фреймвёка не помогла.  MSDN говорит (если я правильно понял), что данное пространство имён содержится в  PresentationFramework.dll, но попытки вставить его в  System32 или в Фреймвёк  ни к чему не привели. Тупик. Помогите, кто может.

Answer (score 1):

> Namespace: System.Windows.Data
>
> Assembly: PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Убедитесь, что у вас подключена данная библиотека.

UP: Подозреваю, что у вас проект на одном фреймворке (3.5 скорее всего), а ссылки на сборки добавляете из другого. В свойствах проекта можно посмотреть какая у вас версия, в свойствах ссылки на сборку можно посмотреть и ее версию.

Comment: Извените дурака,  что конкретно нужно сделать??

Comment: Нужно подключить к проекту ссылку на сборку: PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Не дочитал ваш вопрос, сори... Судя по концовке вы итак были вкурсе, что подключать, но не знаете как что ли?

Comment: http://goo.gl/Gryoh

Comment: Да, конечно,  чисто затупил. Сделал. Результат -                 Imports System.Windows.Data пришло в себя  :)  Однако про  BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(TextBox)   по-прежнему не слава богу:
подчёркнуто и пишет:                                             Reference required to assemble  WindowsBase,   Version = 3.0.0, PublicKeyToken=31b... containing the type System.Windows.Dependency Object.  Add one to your project
Теперь надо Imports System.Windows.Dependency Object   ??
Но такого у меня опять таки нет!:(
И в списке ссылок (http://goo.gl/Gryoh) System.Windows.dll тоже отсутствует (

Comment: Какая версия используемого фреймворка в приложении? Судя по ошибке нужна еще ссылка на WindowsBase: http://goo.gl/0iGxV

Comment: да вот и я этого не совсем понимаю.  Работаю в Visual Studio 2008, Windows7/
В папке C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework лежат следующие папки : 
v1.0.3705 ; v1.1.4322 ; v2.0.50727 ; v3.0 ; v3.5; v4.0.30319.
Короче только 4.5 нет.  И какой из них используется ? Как это узнать?

Comment: Да, WindowsBase.   А теперь он не может преобразовать .(TextBox)
в .Dependency Object.  Я много гуглил про этот BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings.  везде это просто работает.
Гдето у меня бардак в системе, понять бы где  ...

Comment: У вас есть обозреватель решения. В его свойствах (основных или компиляции) можно увидеть под какой фреймворк создан проект и можно изменить там же.